# Get feedback on infinispan asynchronous replication errors

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

We have an infinispan setup in which we replicate some caches to other nodes within the cluster synchronous. This can occasionally cause problems in the putInCache call when one of the other nodes crashes or times out.

It is important for us that the cache changes do arrive on the other nodes, but not that important that a failure should occur in case the cache put doens't arrive in one other node.

We can't use putAsync as ordering of the cache puts is crucial.

What would be ideal for is is using asyns replication, but with feedback on which node did node receive the cache operation so we can take action (for instance, flush the cache on the failing node).

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure how putAsync ordering could be a problem. Even if you have two puts in parallel, you don't know which will be applied first. What you want is that if you have 2 parallel puts, say P1 and P2, they are applied in the same order in the local container as remotely. So, if P1 is applied before P2 locally, same order is guaranteed cluster wide.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño But when you have two sequentially called putAsync()s, these can be applied in the other order

Comment: Indeed Flavious, but if there's a relationship between the two putAsyns's, these should be chained/pipelined to represent that relationship. With CompletableFutures, you'd call thenCompose(). With NotifyingFutures a bit more involved, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible in Infinispan, there is no confirmation when a key was locked and it would be safe to issue another write without having it applied first. You could try to preserve newer values by using `putIfAbsentAsync`/`replaceAsync` instead, or maybe the new [functional API](http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/08/new-functional-map-api-in-infinispan-8.html) that's included in 8.0.

Async replication (DIST_ASYNC, REPL_ASYNC) doesn't fit the bill either: the originating node doesn't receive any confirmation from the other nodes, so there's no way to know when the write is really done. What's more, the ordering you get with async replication is unreliable: writes from different nodes are not ordered, and even writes from the same node can be reordered when the "primary owner" of a key changes.

Comment: No is also an answer (unfortunately) and thanks for the pointers.